# nested if-else statement with same else code

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following code and want to know if there is a better way to use the if-else with same result other than using the same else three times?

```
if($condition1) {
   // some code to get condition 2
   if($condition2) {
      // some code to get condition 3
      if($condition3) {
         $dt = $something;
      } else {
         $dt = "";
      }
   } else {
      $dt = "";
   }
} else {
   $dt = ""; 
}
```

Comment: define varibale `$dt = ""` before if 1st level if statement. Then you don't need to write else part.

Comment: Why don't you go for switch conditions.? It will be good for your conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily get rid of some of the extra `else` statements.

```
$dt = ""; // Assign $dt in the beginning

if ($condition1) {
    // some code to get condition 2
    if ($condition2 && $condition3) {
      // some code to get condition 3
      $dt = $something;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to avoid nested statements.

> using a function

```
$dt = doSomething($params);

function someFunction ($params) {

    if (!$condition1) {
        return "";
    }

    // do stuff for condition 1

    if (!$condition2) {
        return "";
    }

    // do stuff for condition 2

    if (!$condition3) {
        return "";
    }

    return $something;
}
```

> using a do/while statement

```
do {

    $dt = "";

    if (!$condition1) {
        break;
    }

    // do stuff for condition 1

    if (!$condition2) {
        break;
    }

    // do stuff for condition 2

    if (!$condition3) {
        break;
    }

    $dt = $something;

} while (0); // since this will evaluate to false it will not loop at all.
```